# Is deserialization synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, volatile

In this example class, could I be sure that `getTransientObject()` never returns `null` (assuming the field is not assigned `null`) in a multithreaded environment or should I mark the field as `volatile`?

```
public class MySerializable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5697687207743287388L;

    private transient TransientObject transientObject;

    public MySerializable(TransientObject transientObject) {
        this.transientObject = transientObject;
    }

    public TransientObject getTransientObject() {
        return transientObject;
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(transientObject.getId());
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.transientObject = retrieveTransientObject(in.readUTF());
    }

    private static TransientObject retrieveTransientObject(String id) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Depends on how the other thread gets a reference to `MySerializable`.

Comment: If you do one of a few things before the other thread gets a reference to `MySerializable`, then `getTransientObject` will not return `null`. Read the documentation of the [java.util.concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

Comment: The question is whether the desynchronization adds some happens-before relationship when the object is created and initialized. I've read the chapter [17.4.5. (Happens-before Order) of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) (and the documentation you mentioned, which refers to the specification). Neither mentions serialization/deserialization. I assumed it didn't add any happens-before but was unsure, thus the question.